# Why doesn't Ubuntu recognize Windows 10?

Tags: boot-repair, windows-10

How can I fix that Ubuntu when I trying to install it it says that my laptop doesn't have any other operating system.

Comment: Try to disable the fast shutdown and reboot options in Windows 10. They're somewhere in your settings. I don't actually know where but Google will help. Then, hopefully, it is recognized. It may be a UEFI thing but let's try this first.

Answer (score 1):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is an Ubuntu GUI application that can repair the kind of problems that may occur after installing another operating systems to a multi boot partition. You should be familiar with the basic principals of the [GRUB 2 boot loader](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), but Boot-Repair offers you a certain level of automation, and will provide a "Boot-info file" that can be useful in getting help from other users on the Ask Ubuntu Forum. You may need to install this application before you proceed. The following steps will install Boot-Repair on Ubuntu.

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Once you have installed the 'Boot-Repair,' App launch it from >System >Administration >Boot-Repair, or search for boot-repair" from the Dash and launch from there. Select the "Recommended repair" option, or advanced options depending on the extent of your problem.

Further instructions can be found here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Provided that you have already successfully installed Ubuntu.  If you are only just installing Ubuntu to a computer with Windows 10 Installed, Ubuntu Installer should recognise the windows  installation in the process, and offer you the option of installing  [Ubuntu and Windows Dual Boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot). Please expand your question.